# Is there a way to disable responsiveness network-wide? (If not, can we add one?)

Tags: feature-request, support, design, responsive-design

In the footer, there is a "Disable Responsiveness" link that toggles responsiveness **on the current SE site**:

[image: footer-responsiveness-link]

But I don't like responsiveness and would prefer to disable it *across the entire SE network*, by default, without having to do it on each new site I visit. Is this even possible?

If not, would implementing it be a possibility? (For example, there could be a network-wide default and a per-site override, like Discord handles channel permissions, but even an "overwrite all sites' responsiveness with one setting" feature would be quite welcome.)

Comment: IIRC the team's plan is to remove the button once responsive design is fully rolled out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please bring back the option to disable the responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376361/please-bring-back-the-option-to-disable-the-responsiveness)

Answer (score 7):

I see that Joe has marked this status-review, which is great.  I have a request about implementation. Please consider users who use multiple devices.  I would disable responsiveness on my desktop and tablet in a heartbeat, but on my phone I need the full site, not mobile,  if I want to be able to moderate,  and the non-responsive full site is terrible on a phone. Some of y'all see well enough to do that; I don't. Other users might want the responsive design on a non-crowded home machine with a large window,  but want to turn it off when putting two 950px windows next to each other (browser and editor).

These use cases will not be possible if the setting is tied to the *account*; it needs to be possible to control it for a *browser*. A global setting with local override would work.  Please don't just make it global.

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to implement this as a cookie.

Comment: Great idea, thanks! I hadn't even stopped to consider phone users, who responsiveness is _made_ for. (:

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately the latest <del>re</del> undesign broke this :(

A user script to permanently disable responsiveness on the whole network(*)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, disable responsiveness
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968306
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 


(function() {
'use strict';

    var myCookie = getCookie("no-responsiveness");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "no-responsiveness=1";
    }
    
})();
```

(*) I hope I did not forget any sites.

Comment: I didn't try this, but I can't help but expect that it wouldn't work anymore. I think they either removed the cookies or made them not do anything.

Comment: @Laurel You are correct. This won't work anymore. We do not look at that cookie and setting it has no effect. One could instead manually remove the `html__responsive` class from the `<html>` element, but that could only occur after the page is rendered and isn't guaranteed to work permanently.

Comment: @animuson Would it be possible to see an example how this can be done? The responsivity still drives me crazy!

Comment: @Laurel Indeed, the latest undesign broke the script :(