# Make "Disable Responsiveness" persistent even when cookies are cleared / not allowed

Tags: feature-request, responsive-design

Please add an option to make the "Disable Responsiveness" button persistent

[image]

At the moment it seems to rely on cookies set in the browser. This means that the setting is lost if cookies are cleared or not allowed. Please introduce an alternative way to keep this setting, for example by adding it as an option to the user preferences.

I'd be also glad to hear if there are any hacks or users scripts to permanently disable responsiveness, maybe by automatically setting such a cookie like it is done in https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/32906-get-me-old-youtube ?

*(There is a related question which asks to make "disable responsiveness" an network wide option ([Is there a way to disable responsiveness network-wide? (If not, can we add one?)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314211/)) for which introducing some option in the user preferences might also be a solution)*

Comment: A ping to let you know we saw this, but I don't have an ETA on a response. I'm happy to refund your bounty if you want.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for your comment - it is great to see that communications seems to work much better in the last few days! Don't worry about the bounty, I don't care for the rep points and maybe some user has some user script or something as a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Got tired of waiting....

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, disable responsiveness
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968306
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 


(function() {
'use strict';

    var myCookie = getCookie("no-responsiveness");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "no-responsiveness=1";
    }

})();
```