# Stack Exchange on a small resolution screen

Tags: support, design, scrolling

When I'm behind a 1024x768 screen the width of content on this site is decreased making several answers and questions inconvenient to read. How can I have the site loaded with full widths and heights but having scroll bars instead?

When I edit this question I do in fact have a horizontal scroll bar, and I suppose full width. Why is readability more of an aim during editing?!

In addition to the current answer I found 'Hide left navigation' in preferences that makes the problem 164px less bad when responsiveness is on, and improves the position of Q/As when responsiveness is off.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but do you want to disable the responsive design? If yes, there is a button called "Disable Responsiveness" on the very bottom left of the site.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you that button solved the problem

Comment: Just FYI, the "Disable Responsiveness" link is only temporary. You may have to get used to the decreased readability. And to answer your last question, the responsive design has just been applied to a handful of the most used parts of the site. They will eventually bring the responsive design to the editing page.

Comment: [Apparently only about 1% of users as of 2016 use 1024x768 screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272617/135565). I'd almost guess its not tested.  I'm tempted to ask if the mobile view would work as a workaround and... what *is* that resolution in 2018? The worst I've used lately is 1366x768, and I'm curious about oldschool 4:3 screens ;p

Comment: @KodosJohnson My 1024 width is temporary too, but what is planned to be the minimum supported width when the link goes away?

Comment: Inspecting the content element on this page using Chrome dev tools, it looks like minimum width before things start shrinking is 1100 pixels.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Remember that some people have bigger screens but don't maximize the browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The so called "responsive design" can be disabled with a button on the very bottom left of the site:

[image: disable responsiveness button]

Then you will be able to see the content at its natural size. Unfortunately you will have to repeat this process for every Stack Exchange community separately and also repeat it if your clear the cookies of your browser.

To make this permanent for the whole network, you can use the following user script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        StackExchange, disable responsiveness
// @match       *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match       *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match       *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match       *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match       *://*.superuser.com/*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968306
function getCookie(name) {
    var dc = document.cookie;
    var prefix = name + "=";
    var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
    if (begin == -1) {
        begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
        if (begin != 0) return null;
    }
    else
    {
        begin += 2;
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
        end = dc.length;
        }
    }
    // because unescape has been deprecated, replaced with decodeURI
    //return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    return decodeURI(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
} 


(function() {
'use strict';

    var myCookie = getCookie("no-responsiveness");

    if (myCookie == null) {
        document.cookie = "no-responsiveness=1";
    }

})();
```

Comment: If this is only temporary as someone in the comments mentioned, then this answer won't work for long.

Comment: @forest I hope only the button is temporary before the Powers That Be will add some option in the user preferences to make opting out of responsiveness easier.  (related feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316923/make-disable-responsiveness-persistent-even-when-cookies-are-cleared-not-all)

Comment: @forest If this button should really disappear without replacement, one could use userscripts to make the site a bit less broken than it normally is and adjust the widths manually: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7831/36296 https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7815/36296

Comment: @samcarter it shouldn't be a user setting, though; I want different behaviors on different devices.  Adding it to preferences would force one setting on me on every device and in every browser.  This needs to be client-dependent.

Comment: @MonicaCellio A preference if this should be global or not would be good -- because I don't want to redo this on every single site and repeat it whenever I restart my browser ...

Comment: @samcarter on every restart would be a real pain.  I was assuming that SE could remember it on a browser in the same way that it remembers for years on end that I'm logged in.  Doing it on every site is a pain, but I don't know how to make something global to a *platform* but not to a *user everywhere*.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Be assured that on every restart is indeed a pain. My browser cookies are cleared on every restart, so I have to disable the responsiveness every day ... again and again on every site.