# What is the state of the new site designs promised after the redesign?

Tags: support, design, responsive-design, graduating-sites, full-sites

Last year, Jon Ericson wrote in an [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319089/responsive-design-now-available-on-all-sites-new-theme-customization-coming-soo) about the completion of the responsive design rollout:

> We'll continue fixing bugs and starting in 2019 we'll be working on designs for sites with the stock theme. This process used to take a month or more of designer time. With a standard theme, the process will take far less time so more sites will get customizations sooner. Designers will also think a lot less about CSS details and a lot more about how the final design will look. **Sites that have been waiting the longest for their design (Anime and Code Golf come to mind) will be contacted earliest next year on their meta sites.**

<sup>(highlight by me)</sup>

It is now end of February (!= earliest next year). The two named sites ([anime.stackexchange.com](https://anime.stackexchange.com) and [codegolf.stackexchange.com](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com)) still use the Stock theme though and when looking at the community bulletin, I see no announcement/feedback/input posts.

**What is the state of the new site designs?**

I think this is especially important, as faster design process was one of the core promises of the redesign.

Comment: I personally read *earliest next year* as *not sooner then early next year*. Your conclusion that February != earliest next year doesn't hold in my definition. I don't read what Jon said as a definitive time schedule nor a commitment to a specific delivery date. It will still be done within 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: @rene But he already says that the designs will start in 2019 in the first sentence. That was why I interpreted *earliest next year* as *as early as possible*. Well, if this is a mistake by me, it might still be useful to others having the same mistake (as non-native speakers).

Comment: And @rene, I don't see it as a definitive time schedule either, but according to my interpretation, at least a "we want some input on your design" post could have been posted already. Maybe the design is already work in progress (as IIRC both Codegolf and Anime&Manga both had already community-initiated feedback posts).

Comment: I'll personally wait until December 31 before asking. :)

Comment: @Sha December 31 2025? for 6 to 8 years? :P

Comment: Heh, good chance that's when we'll really get new design, but we can ask before. ;-)

Comment: Somewhat connected: [Writing.SE clamours for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322781/writing-se-clamours-for-graduation)

Comment: @Mari-LouA not at all connected. Writing isn't graduated.

Comment: @Catija somewhat connected because they are all waiting for a response or a definite answer.

Comment: No. With the current system, writing would not get a design. Anime is already graduated and is owed one. While we plan to make it possible for beta sites to have a design, they'd still come after all the graduated sites.

Comment: I had asked this basic question of Jon Ericson a couple weeks ago in the Moderators Only chat. He stated two things. First, the Lead person who had been putting out updates on this has left the Stack Exchange network, so they are now working at a deficit. Secondly, he stated he'd be posting something up "pretty soon" as to the status of the graduated sites which are owed site designs. I know Anime & CodeGolf are in the list, but there are several others out there which are waiting. Mechanics has been waiting ~2.5 years for ours as well.

Comment: @Catija Jon seemed to pretty clearly say that designs weren't  restricted to "graduated" sites - part of breaking up with graduation. Writing certainly expects to move off the generic theme even if SE refuses our requests to be done with beta after 9 years. If this is not in fact the case, I would greatly appreciate it if someone would post an update on our meta.

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate: [With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/335251) - We've now [posted an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/335251). It may be worth closing your question as a duplicate of that one, if it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of March 13, 2019, we begun work on new site designs for those sites that are no longer in beta, but haven't received a design yet.

Right now, these are complete:

- [<strike>Programming Puzzles &</strike> Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17548/the-ppcg-site-design-is-on-its-way-help-us-make-it-awesome) (11 June 2019)
- [Anime](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live) (9 July 2019)
- [Arduino](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2729) (12 July 2022)
- [Ethereum](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/719) (14 July 2022)
- [Data Science](https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2631) (10 August 2022)
- [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2136/72070) (10 August 2022)
- [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1128) (16 September 2022)
- [Philosophy](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5365/32494) (16 September 2022)
- [Spanish Language](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4471) (22 September 2022)
- [German Language](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1752) (30 September 2022)
- [French Language](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/906) (30 September 2022)
- [Sound Design](https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1497) (14 December 2022)

We're in progress for a final design based on feedback from the community on:

- [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) ([information gathering](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3576))
- [Quantitative Finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) ([information gathering](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1684))
- [Gardening and Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) ([information gathering](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/961/26017))
- [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) ([information gathering](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2492))
- [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) ([information gathering](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1121))

The remaining sites that are waiting are:

- [Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

I don't have any specifics on the timeline for completing these as we're just ramping up but we're working through the list now! We really appreciate your patience and we're really excited to have these sites getting designs after so long!

Comment: ... for anyone who's skeptical... I've seen the Anime design (in process) and it's really pretty... so this isn't *just* idea collection. ;) (also, the list of sites is actually in order by graduation date, which is the order we're planning to go in... provided we don't get hung up on a site in the process... so don't get clever about alphabetizing the list or anything like that.)

Comment: Anime got their design April 30th; mind updating this post?

Comment: It's not the final design. So, nothing to update.

Comment: Oh, wait, the design that's currently deployed there is subject to change?

Comment: It's being completely redone. See their meta.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing Mechanics get rolling, personally :o) I really couldn't tell you why ;-)

Comment: Wow, Anime and Code Golf look great!

Comment: The Anime theme is lovely. Code Golf not so great but still better than some of SE's modernized and soulless themes which were updated last year...

Comment: BTW I applaud the decision to write the name of the month rather than use the American calendar order: month, day, year (e.g. 7/12/19) because for *the rest of the world* "12" could be interpreted as December. Not so much today but in 2020 this dating could lead to ambiguity, so thank you for choosing clarity over style!

Comment: Is this going to be updated for the 29 sites that left beta last year?