# How's site design going for smaller out-of-beta sites?

Tags: discussion, design, full-sites

I'm curious about the progress towards site design for multiple [out-of-beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331708/congratulations-to-our-29-oldest-beta-sites-theyre-now-no-longer-beta) [sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites), particularly smaller sites, which are yet to have a design.

I understand this is not a straightforward process and don't want to add pressure; I'm just after some idea of how it's going.  I recall there was a Zoom meeting awhile back (maybe ~4 months ago), and this topic was raised then, but I think the general answer was "we'll have to get back to you on this".

**Question**: How's site design going for smaller out-of-beta sites?

(I didn't immediately find a relevant post here on meta.)

Comment: I'd rather see all over 7 years old Beta sites have their Beta labels first: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331728/215590

Comment: I asked about this in October and [was told](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355660/mse-feedback-post-feedback-on-q4-2020-community-and-public-platform-roadmap/355675#comment1188887_355675) that there was no bandwidth for site designs due to a lack of staffing.

Comment: I am not sure whether there was some official announcement since this post: [What is the state of the new site designs promised after the redesign?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324421#326798) (The last update is from 2019 - there were edits after that, but it was copy-editing rather than adding new information.)

Comment: Relevant, possible duplicate: [With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378888/335251) - We've now [posted an answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/335251). It may be worth closing your question as a duplicate of that one, if it makes sense to do so.