# When will Blender Stack Exchange get dark mode?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, dark-mode

In 2020, Stack Overflow finally got its [dark mode release](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/31/building-dark-mode-on-stack-overflow/).

When will it be available on [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: For the latest update: [Staff's answer to "With new designs planned for some sites, are there plans to tackle the backlog?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/241919): "*we also have some ideas around increasing accessibility and customization by bringing dark mode and other more accessible-centric designs beyond Stack Overflow.*"