# Please bring back the option to disable the responsiveness

Tags: feature-request, responsive-design

Please bring back the option to view the site at a fixed width. I like to have SO on one half of the screen and my editor on the other half, but after losing the "Disable responsiveness" option from the footer

[image: Disable responsiveness link circled]

I'm barely able to see any content. Compare the following two images, on the left with a fixed width and on the right with responsiveness enabled.

[image: comparison images]

Before losing this option, I was able to see more than 4 questions at once, with the responsiveness, there are just 3.5 questions.

Comment: I doubt this will happen. This option was always advertised from day one as a *temporary* option while responsiveness was being worked on. We never intended to make it a permanent feature.

Comment: It's relatively easy to take a responsive layout and find a width where it is inconvenient

Comment: @animuson ... so is there any other way to get a usable site?

Comment: make it a tiny bit smaller, and the sidebar will drop to the bottom of the page. Bonus points for having more room for your editor.

Comment: @Luuklag yes, but then I can't simply use window snapping to arrange my windows and have to switch to the mouse to fine tune the size.

Comment: zoom in a touch

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz as a MAC user I never have that problem.

Comment: @Luuklag I'm also on a mac, please enlighten me how this solves the problem?

Comment: @KevinB If I zoom in, I do get the messed up question list with the vote/answer count at the top of the box instead of the front, which makes it very hard to look for questions which still need an answer.

Comment: So, do we really need to disable responsiveness, or do we need to give you a way to optionally collapse the right sidebar? I don't think the first one, "Not responsive" is what the page would have looked like previously, if you had responsiveness disabled - it would have still had the right sidebar, no? Maybe I'm confused because I didn't usually use that option.

Comment: @Catija I don't need the right sidebar, removing it would also solve the problem. Previously I had a user script to remove it, but it stopped working in one of the many redesigns :(  In the screenshot without responsiveness, the right sidebar is still there, but outside of the visible area where it does not interfere (notice the scrollbar at the bottom)

Comment: @Catija Using the button worked as a workaround for the bug that the dialog for reviewing suggested edits from posts themselves isn't usable on mobile (the pop-up is not responsive). At least until that bug is fixed, the button should be reinstated. (It was filed quite a long time ago and still hasn't been fixed, meaning it's likely a complicated fix.)

Comment: @catija removing this option has made the site barely useable on mobile for me. It will not allow me to zoom out far enough to read even a single question or answer on one screen. please bring it back!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz because there is no automatic snapping to the half of the window, as Mircrosoft has. It was meant with some sarcasm.

Comment: @Luuklag Luckily there are plenty of apps. BetterTouchTools is probably the most commonly used one, but personally I prefer https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle