# Please allow me to decrease zoom on mobile

Tags: feature-request, design, mobile-web, responsive-design

Since the new site design, when using mobile chrome, I can fit maybe a third of a question or answer on the screen at once, in giant lettering.

I was able to get around it, by clicking "disable responsive design". the resulting page was ugly, but it allowed me to pinch-zoom outwards as much as I wanted. But now that is gone as well.

Please, I beg you, allow me to zoom outwards! This is not useable as it is. Or let me decrease the font and whitespace scaling in some other way.

this is how it looks for me:
[image: mobile view]

It is impossible to zoom out further than this, so I cannot fit even a single question or answer on the screen, barely a paragraph. I can easily zoom inwards, so zooming is not disabled entirely.

I can click "request desktop site" in chrome settings to get something readable, but this is a global setting. most other sites I visit become unreadable when it is enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please bring back the option to disable the responsiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376361/please-bring-back-the-option-to-disable-the-responsiveness)

Comment: @sonic no, I am aware that staff has said they won't bring "disable responsiveness" back, and it was a bad workaround anyway. This feature request simply asks for enabling further zoom levels on mobile on the normal page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views)

Comment: That's a fair request, many people use Large Fonts on their system due to eyesight problems, or for their own reasons. **Close voters: this isn't a request to disable responsiveness or bring back mobile view. It's a very specific request to bring back a single feature. It is not a duplicate of any question.**

Comment: @rob no, the question you linked announces the new site design, I am requesting an usability feature for this design: less magnification/ zooming outwards

Comment: I had the same / similar issue with my Chrome app on my Samsung - but selecting "Desktop Site" via the top-right three dots has improved it somewhat.

Comment: HugoRune, The [duplicate that I suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) says: "Instead of maintaining both of these, we’re going to unship the mobile view and opt everyone into the responsive views by default.". **If** you want smaller fonts on the entire page that's the place to post your Feedback (answer); on the Announcement (question) - That's how `duplicates on Announcements` work here at MSE. They have already set an accessible font size. If you want smaller (zoom out) you need to [do that on your end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qd0Pk.jpg).

Comment: @Rob it's an old announcement with lots of answers already. Let's be realistic, the chances a developer will see such answer and act upon it is nearly zero.

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron does the person who posted the question see it?

Comment: @Rob yes they see it, but over the years, by posting comments and answers addressing developers, I learned one thing: they never respond. Not unless it's a fresh thing and they explicitly asked for feedback. So I learned my lesson and stopped trying.